# Is there a size limitation for an Access DB destination in SSIS?

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I'm creating an SSIS package, which will read through a user's SQL database and populate the tables in an Access database. However, for the largest user databases, I start getting errors around the time the Access file reaches approx. 2 GB.

Has anyone run into this problem? Is this a size limitation for this operation?

More information: I'm getting the error code 0xC020907B, but no additional information that I can see.

> Error: 0xC0209029 at ,
>    [733]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. 
>   The "input "OLE DB Destination Input"
>   (746)" failed because error code
>   0xC020907B occurred, and the error row
>   disposition on "input "OLE DB
>   Destination Input" (746)" specifies
>   failure on error. An error occurred on
>   the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.

Comment: Why did you choose Jet/ACE as your data store without bothering to investigate its limitations in regard to file size?

Comment: Short answer: I didn't. The decision was made before I came to the company, and right now we're sticking with it for back-compatibility. No doubt we'll be looking for something different soon (especially as databases inch closer to the 2 GB threshold) but at the moment, that change isn't in the cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum size of an Access database is 2 GB.

Comment: is correct.  The maximum size in any case for Access is 2GB.  This has nothing to do with SSIS. Any input method would have the same issue.